# How to retrieve file from broken samsung

Tags: samsung, files

I have a broken Samsung Express GT-I8730 which keeps rebooting every 5 sec.
There is no sd card in the phone but I need the pictures that are on the phone.

In recovery mode, the phone is not seen by the computer.
I cannot copy the photos because it reboots to fast.

Is there any way to retrieve them without starting up the phone?

Comment: Have you tried a different battery, on the off chance this one is borked?

Comment: I dont have another battery. Also I dont think it is the battery because in recovery mode it does not reboot

Comment: I'd suggest trying a new battery anyway. Keep in mind that there's more than one way a battery can go bad. If the battery can't hold a charge, then the recovery and splash screens won't run either, of course. However, it could be that the battery can hold a charge but the voltage has dropped to a level that's sufficient for recovery and startup graphics, but once the OS starts the current is insufficient so it crashes within seconds. Mobile device batteries are dirt cheap, so it's worth a try before giving up on the phone.

Comment: Case in point, I had a Samsung phone start rebooting at random times while running, and at one point it stopped completing the boot process. I could go into recovery (stock and custom), and if I tried to boot to the system, it would go through the startup animations, stay at the bright red Verizon splash screen for about 15 seconds, then restart. Over and over and over. So it obviously had enough charge to show the startup graphics multiple times, but the OS couldn't run. I swapped the battery and it never happened again. Also, I put that battery in another phone and the same thing happened.

Comment: And is it possible to measure the amount of volts to be sure? If so.. Do you perhaps know how many volts the battery need to support?

Answer (score 0):

If you had Auto Backup turned on in Google Photos, you can retrieve them through your browser at https://plus.google.com/photos.

Comment: No I dont have a backup